# How to tell which commit a tag points to in Git?

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a bunch of unannotated tags in the repository and I want to work out which commit they point to. Is there a command that that will just list the tags and their commit SHAs? Checking out the tag and looking at the HEAD seems a bit too laborious to me.

### Update

I realized after I went through the responses that what I actually wanted was to simply look at the history leading up to the tag, for which `git log <tagname>` is sufficient.

The answer that is marked as answer is useful for getting a list of tags and their commits, which is what I asked. With a bit of shell hackery I'm sure it's possible to transform those into SHA+Commit message.

Comment: I want to point that `git show-ref` shows sha of the tag, not sha of the repo revision.

    $ git show-ref test

    08b9c774ab20e5bdb638339cf4ea2c124b0dae54 refs/tags/test

    $ git checkout test

    HEAD is now at c7f8831...

    $ git checkout 08b9c77

    HEAD is now at c7f8831...

Comment: if your tags are annotated then you need `--dereference`

Answer (score 510, accepted):

One way to do this would be with `git rev-list`. The following will output the commit to which a tag points:

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 $TAG
```

**NOTE This works for both Annotated and Unannotated tags**

You could add it as an alias in `~/.gitconfig` if you use it a lot:

```
[alias]
  tagcommit = rev-list -n 1
```

And then call it with:

```
$ git tagcommit $TAG
```

Possible pitfall: if you have a local checkout or a branch of the same tag name, this solution might get you "**warning: refname 'myTag' is ambiguous**". In that case, try increasing specificity, e.g.:

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 tags/$TAG
```

Comment: I've actually found that on windows (in bash shell and normal cmd line client) I don't need to do `| head -n 1` as rev-list just returns the SHA.

Comment: Why not use `git rev-parse <tag>`? Or `git rev-list -1 <tag>`?

Comment: @ Jakub: `git rev-parse $TAG` returns the SHA1 of the tag object, not the commit to which it points. `git rev-list -1` works, though.

Comment: @mipadi: For **un-annotated** tags it soedn't matter; for annotated tags you can use `git rev-parse $TAG^{commit}` or `git rev-parse $TAG^{}` to dereference annotated/signed tag

Comment: @AndySmith: It prints the commit hash on one line.

Comment: That alias didn't work in Windows, so I made one that does: https://gist.github.com/jonathanconway/5667042.

Comment: You can use: `git rev-list $TAG --max-count=1`

Comment: @Jakub: What is the difference of the two (rev-parse $TAG, and rev-list -1 $TAG)? Can you give an example?  In my experiment, they returns the same sha1 code.  What differs a tag object from the commit pointed to by the tag?

Comment: @RobinHsu: if you have ***annotated*** tags, that is created with `git tag -a` or `git tag -s`, then `git rev-parse <tag>` would give you SHA-1 of a *tag object* itself, while `git rev-list -1 <tag>` would give SHA-1 of *commit* (revision) it points to, same as `git rev-parse <tag>^{commit}`. HTH.

Comment: If you have a local checkout of the tag, `git rev-list -n 1 x` might get you "**warning: refname 'x' is ambiguous.**". To avoid that, you can increase specificity like so: `git rev-list -n 1 tags/x`

Comment: If tag does not exist the command shows error `fatal: ambiguous argument 'mytag': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`.

Answer (score 285):

**WARNING This only works for Unannotated tags** Therefore it is safer to use the accepted answer which works in the general case https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862542/1586965

```
git show-ref --tags
```

For example, `git show-ref --abbrev=7 --tags` will show you something like the following:

```
f727215 refs/tags/v2.16.0
56072ac refs/tags/v2.17.0
b670805 refs/tags/v2.17.1
250ed01 refs/tags/v2.17.2
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this actually hides the semantics of looking at either `.git/packed-refs` or `.git/refs/tags/*`

Comment: hmmm. it has strange behavior in my repository: git tag -a v0.1.1-alpha a9dcc1f24cacde535523bddc22f4c69467428550; git show-ref --tags ->b784145a9a71478337f5ceae30aaac4e1b955ee5 refs/tags/v0.1.1-alpha ; see Jakub Narebski 's answer

Comment: @CharlesB: The question asked for a command that listed multiple tags. Also, there is no point to using an explicit ref with `--tags`, an explicit ref will work even if the ref is a lightweight tag.

Comment: this works, although I wonder wouldn't it make sense to have `git tag --verbose` show them too?

Comment: This will show the ref of the tag itself, not the commit the tag points to.  You need to add the `-d` flag to get the referenced commit (on a second line).

Comment: @OldPro: from the question: "I have a bunch of unannotated tags", so these are lightweight tags. `git show-ref --tags` is simplest and sufficient in this case.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, fair enough, but the question and answers have morphed to include annotated tags and the fact that `git show-ref` behaves differently on the two different types of tags is not obvious or common knowledge.

Comment: The result is not the referenced commit, @OldPro is right.

Answer (score 131):

Just use `git show <tag>`

However, it also dumps commit diffs. To omit those diffs, use `git log -1 <tag>`. (Thanks to @DolphinDream and @demisx !)

Comment: On SO, when a question has many different possible answers, the answers that are posted first get upvoted first - putting them at the top of the list, and thus getting them more upvotes later.  This is a biasing feedback loop based on speed of response over quality of response.  With sufficient imagination this problem could be fixed.

Comment: "Best solution" for what? If the interest is in finding out the SHA of a commit the tag points to the "git show <mytag>" is NOT the best solution.  This command will show the entire diff the commit introduces. For listing only the SHA of the commit the tag points to the "git rev-list <mytag> -n 1" is the correct solution.

Comment: This is not the answer to the OP's  question. `git show <tag>` shows the diff, not the commit the tag points to.

Comment: @demisx What are you talking about?? It definitely shows the commit hash, along with tagger, date, and other information. Try it.

Comment: @Hlung Like @DolphinDream pointed out, `git show` dumps a whole lot more stuff on the screen that doesn't need to be there. It obscures the actual commit hash one is looking for. A better command is `git log -1 [tag-name]` or `git log -1 --pretty=oneline [tag-name]` if you want oneliners.

Comment: @demisx You are right. I happened to do `git show` only on commit that doesn't show diffs in the command line up until now (e.g. merge commits). That's where I usually put tags on. I agree with `git log -1 [tag-name]` is cleaner. I'll add a note to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: git show shows too much information when all you need is the commit SHAs

Comment: @DolphinDream Best solution for people who want to do exactly this, but won't ask another question, coz it'd be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: This solution, with its verbose output, actually helped me to solve my particular problem more than the solution with the concise output, correct though it may be.

Answer (score 58):

From [Igor Zevaka](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1862423/3):

### Summary

Since there are about 4 almost equally acceptable yet different answers I will summarise all the different ways to skin a tag.

1. `git rev-list -1 $TAG` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862542/456814)). `git rev-list` outputs the commits that lead up to the `$TAG` similar to `git log` but only showing the SHA1 of the commit. The `-1` limits the output to the commit it points at.
2. `git show-ref --tags` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863224/456814)) will show all tags (local and fetched from remote) and their SHA1s.
3. `git show-ref $TAG` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863712/456814)) will show the tag and its path along with the SHA1.
4. `git rev-parse $TAG` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863712/456814)) will show the SHA1 of an unannotated tag.
5. `git rev-parse --verify $TAG^{commit}` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863712/456814)) will show a SHA1 of both annotated and unannotated tags. On Windows use `git rev-parse --verify %TAG%^^^^{commit}` (four hats).
6. `cat .git/refs/tags/*` or `cat .git/packed-refs` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862464/456814)) depending on whether or not the tag is local or fetched from remote.

Answer (score 48):

For annotated tags, `git show-ref TAG` shows the tag's hash, not the hash of the commit it points to.

`git show-ref --dereference TAG` shows, additionally, the commit being pointed at with an added `^{}`.

Answer (score 38):

Use

```
git rev-parse --verify <tag>^{commit}
```

(which would return SHA-1 of a commit even for annotated tag).

---

`git show-ref <tag>` would also work if `<tag>` is not annotated.  And there is always `git for-each-ref` (see documentation for details).

Comment: I prefer `git rev-parse <tag>~0` which also seems to work, and requires no special escaping on Windows (on which four hats (^) are necessary instead of one). The suffix `~<number>` gives the <number>th parent commit, therefore `~0` yields the commit itself. Btw, `^0` is also a valid shorthand for the `^{commit}` revision suffix.

Answer (score 15):

How about this:

```
git log -1 $TAGNAME
```

OR

```
git log -1 origin/$TAGNAME
```

Answer (score 13):

In order to get the sha/hash of the commit that a tag refers to (not the sha of the tag):

`git rev-list -1 <tag>`

Answer (score 11):

**Short post-Git-2 answer**

I know this question has been out here for quite a while. And the answer from CB Bailey is 100% correct: `git show-ref --tags --abbrev`

I like this one better since it uses `git tag`:

```
git tag --list --format '%(refname:short) %(objectname:short)'
```

Simple. Short.

PS alias it as `git taglist` with this command:

```
git config --global alias.taglist "tag --list --format '%(refname:short) %(objectname:short)'"
```

Comment: For annotated tags, this gives the tag hash instead of the commit hash.

Answer (score 10):

The `--format` option can be used to show both tag hash and the commit hash, and to distinguish between lightweight and annotated tags.

```
git tag --format="%(color:bold cyan)== %(refname:short) ==%(if)%(object)%(then)%0aTag Hash: %(objectname)%0aTag Date: %(taggerdate:iso-local)%0a  Commit: %(object) %0a%0a%(contents)%(else)%0a(lightweight tag)%0a  Commit: %(objectname)%(end)%0a"
```

Gives output similar to:

```
== b2lightweight ==
(lightweight tag)
  Commit: 0450fae4352dbbbf088419757eda32711316a02e

== c3_annotated ==
Tag Hash: 19961d8678a09a319a9d6c398c79f27cc23d610c
Tag Date: 2021-08-06 15:18:48 -0600
  Commit: 85be6e80c109ce44d78f0ca0da8e1ec53817b24c

This is my tag message.

It has multiple lines.

Another line.
```

To define as a git alias, you can edit the global git config with `git config --global -e` and add the following:

```
[alias]
    tag-verbose = tag --format='%(color:bold cyan)== %(refname:short) ==%(if)%(object)%(then)%0aTag Hash: %(objectname)%0aTag Date: %(taggerdate:iso-local)%0a  Commit: %(object) %0a%0a%(contents)%(else)%0a(lightweight tag)%0a  Commit: %(objectname)%(end)%0a'
```

The alias still allows filtering, e.g.

```
C:\playground>git tag-verbose -l *b2*
== b2lightweight ==
(lightweight tag)
  Commit: 0450fae4352dbbbf088419757eda32711316a02e
```

For additional information on the `--format` options see the "Field Names" section under `git help for-each-ref`. (`git help tag` states "The format is the same as that of git-for-each-ref")

Answer (score 9):

I'd also like to know the "right" way, but in the meantime, you can do this:

```
git show mytag | head -1
```

Comment: With commit title `git show --oneline mytag | head -1`

Answer (score 7):

Even though this is pretty old, I thought I would point out a cool feature I just found for listing tags with commits:

```
git log --decorate=full
```

It will show the branches which end/start at a commit, and the tags for commits.

Answer (score 5):

You could as well get more easy-to-interpret picture of where tags point to using

```
git log --graph |git name-rev --stdin --tags |less
```

and then scroll to the tag you're looking for via `/`.

More compact view (`--pretty=oneline`) plus all heads (`-a`) could also help:

```
git log -a --pretty=oneline --graph |git name-rev --stdin --tags |less
```

Looks a bit terrifying, but could also be aliased in `~/.gitconfig` if necessary.

```
~/.gitconfig

[alias]
ls-tags = !git log -a --pretty=oneline --graph |git name-rev --stdin --tags |less
```

Answer (score 4):

From [git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqh8u1efh5.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/), here is the way to get the list of commit hashes for tags with automatic dereferencing for annotated tags:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(if)%(*objectname)%(then)%(*objectname)%(else)%(objectname)%(end) %(refname)' refs/tags
```

Comment: Of the many different ways that are called out in this SO, this was the only one that appears to give me a *list* of tags and the *commits* they point to. It appears to require that my local repo fetched the tags from remote, but this is an OK assumption for my use-case. TYSM for posting this answer!

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't show the filenames, but at least you get a feel of the repository.

```
cat .git/refs/tags/*
```

Each file in that directory contains a commit SHA pointing to a commit.

Comment: This didn't work as, I think, I pulled the tags from remote. `.git/packed-refs` did work though.

Answer (score 3):

git rev-list --no-walk [tag_name]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

i'd also like to know *the right way*, but you can always peek either into:

```
$ cat .git/packed-refs
```

or:

```
$ cat .git/refs/tags/*
```

Comment: Right, so behaviour for packed-refs and refs/tags is somewhat different, packed-refs is a text file containing tags and SHAs, whereas refs/tags/ is a directory with text files named after a tag containing the SHA. I actually think that the *proper* way of doing this is with `git rev-list`.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the current SHA1 hash

Abbreviated Commit Hash

```
git show <tag> --format="%h" --> 42e646e
```

Commit Hash

```
git show <tag> --format="%H" --> 42e646ea3483e156c58cf68925545fffaf4fb280
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work in the version I have, but `git log <tag> -n 1 --pretty=%H` does

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to see the details of the tag SOMETAG (tagger, date, etc), the hash of the commit it points to and a bit of info about the commit but without the full diff, try

```
git show --name-status SOMETAG
```

Example output:

```
tag SOMETAG
Tagger: ....
Date:   Thu Jan 26 17:40:53 2017 +0100

 .... tag message .......

commit 9f00ce27c924c7e972e96be7392918b826a3fad9
Author: .............
Date:   Thu Jan 26 17:38:35 2017 +0100

 .... commit message .......

..... list of changed files with their change-status (like git log --name-status) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a load of release folders, where those folders may be checked out from one of a few different repos, and may be dev, qa or master branches or may be production releases, checked out from a tag, and the tag may be annotated or not.  I have a script that will look at the target folder and get be back an answer in the form -.  The problem is different versions of git return different status' for a tag checkout.

So I found `git show-ref --tags` worked initially, except for the annotated tags.  However adding -d added a separate entry to the list of tags, one for the tag, the other for the annotation (the annotation commit was identified as ^{} which I stripped out with sed).

So this is the core of my script, for anyone that wants it:-

```
REPO=`git --git-dir=${TARGET} remote show origin -n | \
         grep "Fetch URL:" | \
         sed -E "s/^.*\/(.*)$/\1/" | \
         sed "s/.git$//"`

TAG=`git --git-dir=${TARGET} show-ref -d --tags | \
         grep \`git --git-dir=${TARGET} show --quiet --format=format:%H HEAD\` | \
         cut -d\  -f2 | \
         cut -d/ -f3 | \
         sed "s/\^{}$//"`

if [ "${TAG}" == "" ] ; then 
  BRANCH=`git --git-dir=${TARGET} show-ref --heads | \
         grep \`git --git-dir=${TARGET} show --quiet --format=format:%H HEAD\` | \
         cut -d\  -f2 | \
         cut -d/ -f3`
  TAG=${BRANCH}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use below, It will give the commit hash
`git show -s --format=%H <tag>^{commit}`

If abbreviated commit hash required, `git show -s --format=%h <tag>^{commit}`

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution

Parse the `.git/packed-refs` and format it as `{tag}\t{sha}`

```
sed -n '/ refs\/tags/ { s@\([^ ]*\) refs/tags/\(.*\)@\2\t\1@; p}' .git/packed-refs
```