# List tags with commits in the same format like git branch -v

Tags: git, tags

Hi I would like to **list tags** like it's listed by:

```
# git branch -v
* devel  e7f5e36 firxed bugs
  master 63e9c56 remove unused code
```

without the * (you can't checkout tag).

It would be good to have an option to list full or short SHA1. A bash script is also fine, but it would be nice to use git commands more and shell scripting less.

I've read this question [How to tell which commit a tag points to in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/git-how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to) and it helped me, but it's not all I want.

Edit:

I didn't know that annotated tags had SHA1. I wanted SHA1 of commits that tag points to, not the tags themselfs.

Comment: There is an *insanely* detailed example in the [`git-for-each-ref` manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) - pared down substantially it would do what you want. When I get a chance I'll write something up for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Removed old stuff, update with formatting

Simplest *git porcelain* way to get the most info:

```
git show-ref --tags --abbrev
```

*(loose the `--abbrev` for full sha1)*

Full bells and whistles:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname) %(objectname) %(subject)" |
      grep /tags/ |
      sed 's#^refs/tags/##'
```

Typical output:

```
tag1 b93d2f5e5ad52b8abbee9f5ca8435a1d271ddbb6 test
tag2 b93d2f5e5ad52b8abbee9f5ca8435a1d271ddbb6 test
tag3 58b05fd27be9484bf981752e89843bee7aff8860 test2
tag4 b1be7e4de8949b7ba515e4cad5d214dc71d9b6d2 annotated
tag5 779528366646eeef1d87d30fa3d76c70d0493dff and signed
```

To clone my test repo:

```
base64 -d <<HERE > /tmp/so5529735.bundle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HERE

git clone --mirror /tmp/so5529735.bundle /tmp/so5529735.git
```

Cheers

Comment: neither of the 2 solutions show all tags. I think it show only annotated tags. the second one has a chance if formatted with awk. I also need to have an option to show full SHA1

Comment: I found out why a tag was missing. I have 2 tags to the same commit: `initial` and `v0.1.1`. only one of them is showing. `initial` is unannotated (without message). `initial` is showing and `v0.1.1` is not

Comment: Annotated tags have it's own SHA1. I guess it's possible to use it like I'm using commit SHA1? For example if I want an archive can I do: `git archive <tag object SHA1>`? Will it export the commit that tag points to? What about all other git functions (like creating a branch). In all my scripts I convert branches and tags to commits and I use it as commits. Asking because `git for-each-ref | grep /tags/` shows tag SHA1 (and not SHA1 of commit that tag points to) when not lightweight.

Comment: Formatting is a bit of pain, but if I succeed I'll edit your post, append my solution and accept your answer. btw `|grep commit` was excluding the annotated tags tags in your second example

Comment: well, it's shorter, but doesn't do what I want. It only formats well if tags are the same width. I have tags with different widths. I'll post difference between results of your solution and mine. If you could get with a more clean/short solution I'll be glad

Comment: I think I'll pass. I rather stay at the information side of things. If you want to prettify the output that is no longer in my git interest area... sry; I'll have a look once you have your requirements clear :)

Comment: It doesn't matter. It helped to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Result of sehe's version:

```
# git for-each-ref --format="%(refname) %(objectname) %(subject)" \
  | grep /tags/ |       sed 's#^refs/tags/##'
initial a9dcc1f24cacde535523bddc22f4c69467428550 initial commit
v0.1.1-alpha b784145a9a71478337f5ceae30aaac4e1b955ee5 initial version. big chance to work. not quite tested
v0.1.2-alpha 193993aabb0c3634ebea0405ecd420e99c609422 it is still alpha
v0.1.3-alpha 415fb8f25982233b1b1211d8500e923e40ce64fd works better. not tested in details.
```

result of sehe's version with short output (like default output git branch -v):

```
# git for-each-ref --format="%(refname) %(objectname:short) %(subject)" \
   | grep /tags/ |       sed 's#^refs/tags/##'
initial a9dcc1f initial commit
v0.1.1-alpha b784145 initial version. big chance to work. not quite tested
v0.1.2-alpha 193993a it is still alpha
v0.1.3-alpha 415fb8f works better. not tested in details.
```

Result of my version:

```
initial      a9dcc1f initial commit
v0.1.1-alpha a9dcc1f initial version. big chance to work. not quite tested
v0.1.2-alpha 8dd326d it is still alpha
v0.1.3-alpha 54d7ccd works better. not tested in details.
```

Here **initial** is lightweight tag

Difference:

1. (most imortant) First column is automatically padded to biggest tag length - it's more readable
2. SHA1 is of commit that the tag points to even if it's not **lightweight tag**. This way you can easily see that **initial** points to is the same commit as **v0.1.1-alpha**. This behavior can easily be made optional.

My script is too long. I'll post only git calling function (bash script). Most of it is taken from git-for-each-ref man page:

```
function gitTags(){
  arg="$1"
  REF=${arg:-"*"}
  fmt='
    r=%(refname)
    t=%(*objecttype)
    T=${r#refs/tags/}
    o=%(*objectname:short)
    s=%(subject)
    kind="T"
    if [ "$t" = "" ] ; then
      # could be a lightweight tag
      t=%(objecttype)
      kind="L"
      o=%(objectname:short)
    fi
    len=${#T}
    if [ "$len" -gt ${len1:-0} ]; then
      len1=$len
    fi

    echo -e "$T\t$o\t$s"
  '
  eval=`git for-each-ref --shell --format="$fmt" \
          --sort='*objecttype' --sort=taggerdate "refs/tags/$REF"`

  out=`eval "$eval"'echo $len1;'`
  local len1=`echo "$out"|tail -n 1`

  echo "$out"|head -n -1 \
     |awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{printf("%-'$len1's %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3)}'

}
```

usage:

```
#show all tags:
gitTags
#show all tags starting with v (v1.0)
gitTags v*
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP said he wanted the SHA1 of the commit that the tags points to.  The above solutions given by sehe and NickSoft don't give the SHA1 of the commit when the tag is an annotated tag.  Instead, they give the SHA1 of the annotation object being pointed to.  (The annotation object points to the commit.)

If you want to list every tag and the SHA1 of the commit, then you can simply execute:

```
    git log --tags --oneline --decorate=short
```

Unfortunately, that won't give you a format that is similar to

```
    git branch -v
```

But you can come pretty close by executing:

```
    git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/tags | 
    awk '{printf "%s ",$1; system("git rev-list --max-count=1 "$1)}'
```

Note that git rev-list will give you the SHA1 of the commit, but git show-ref and git for-each-ref only give the SHA1 of the object being pointed to (which in the case of an annotated tag is the annotation object not the commit).