# Preventing git tags from appearing on certain branches

Tags: git

In git, I want to limit tags to being created only on certain branches. For instance, I want a developer to be able to push tags to origin/master/RLS but not to origin/master/DEV. Any recommendations on how to do that?

Comment: This question is a little unclear. Are you saying that, basically, you only want your developers to be able to tag certain branches, but not others? If that is the case, then there's no built-in mechanism that I'm aware of that will do that. Git will let your developers tag whatever branch they darn well please. Also, is `origin/master/RLS` a remote branch on the origin remote that's namespaced under a folder called `master`, or am I reading that incorrectly? What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/concepts.html#auth) like gitolite.

Take a look [at refex](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#refex) or [VREF](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#vref) (also [detailed here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook.html#cb-vrefs)); a VREF is like an update hook, except that:

- you can define many VREFs
- you can associate a VREF with people and repos: for certains people and certains repo, a certain VREF will apply (that is the point of gitolite: put access rules against access requests done by authenticated people).

In your case, you can define a VREF (a post-update hook script) which will:

- check if a tag is pushed (as in [this update hook example](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7b69fcb181941fafda99a5ffd25cea1f685d7e70/Documentation/howto/update-hook-example.txt#L73))
- [get the commit for that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862542/6309)
- check if  that [commit is part of a branch you don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)