# Are git tags always based on fixed commits

Tags: git, git-tag

On the git tag man page, I read that tags can be created from a commit or on object (e.g. a branch), like the following:

```
git tag mytag master
```

But is the tag internally based on a fixed commit? i.e. if `master` disappears or a new commit is added to `master`, then will the commit the tag references change? In my own experiments, it appears that the tag always references the same fixed commit, but I would like to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if master disappears or a new commit is added to master, then will the commit the tag references change?

No it won't change: the tag is applied on the commit referenced by master when creating said tag.

You can see the commit referenced by the tag with:

```
git rev-parse <tag>~0
```

See more at "[How to tell which commit a tag points to in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863712/6309)".

This is for both lightweight and annotated tags.

Comment: Is this always the case no matter how the tag is created?

Comment: @simonzack yes, for lightweight or annotated tag. The idea of a tag os to be a fixed reference. Not a shifting one.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed delete a branch and the tag will still reference the commit and any parents of that commit that also aren't contained within another branch.

You're still able to checkout the tag and it still shows up in git log and tools like gitg.