# All git command's throwing error when running form sh script(groovy)?

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to get the tagged commit hash.
From terminal command is working fine:

[image: Command line image]

But when I am running the same command from sh script like this:

```
tagged_commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """
                                    git rev-list -1 v1
                                    """)
```

It is showing me this error.

[image]

I have tried all the commands listed here on this link:
[How to tell which commit a tag points to in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to-in-git)

For all these commands it's showing the same error.

Note: I am trying to use this from groovy.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: Maybe check the "pwd" inside the "sh" command...

Comment: Error is not because of some authorization issue. I think It's not even recognizing the argument.

Comment: Getting the working directory doesn't have anything to do with authorization.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Jenkins issue, not a Git issue and not a groovy issue.  When Jenkins clones a Git repository, it often uses a shallow and/or single-branch clone that omits lots of names, including tag names like `v1`.  Such a clone must be expanded to a full—or at least, less-shallow—clone, or made initially as a  full clone.

I have used, but never actually *administered*, Jenkins, and the documentation I could find on Jenkins was always woefully inadequate, so I do not know how to control the initial clone.  If necessary, see existing SO postings on [how to convert a shallow clone to a full clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/1256452).